# How to resolve duplicate devices in Apple Developer centre

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have just renewed an Apple Developer Account and have noticed that I have duplicate entries for my iPad. If I try to enable one of them, I get the following error:

[image]

Both are listed in my devices list. However, the device ID does not match the one I see in XCode / iTunes (it is definitely the same iPad)

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to call Apple directly from https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php
and after a few days they removed my duplicate devices!